# ContentDialog vs Menu Hamburger (SplitView)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, splitview

I have two elements in my project, ContentDialog & SplitView (Hamburger Menu).
My ContentDialog has a button that lets you invoke the SplitView and put the `IsPaneOpen = true`, but when I do, the split view opens and is behind the ContentDialog.

Is there any way to put SplitView above ContentDialog without Dialog disappear?

I've tried placing the Canvas, but nothing worked.

Button code-behind:

```
 private void ButtonMenuClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((App)(App.Current)).HamburgerPage.ShowHamburgerMenu(sender, e);
        }
```

In page of Hamburger Menu:

```
 public void ShowHamburgerMenu(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (splitView.IsPaneOpen)
            {
                this.splitView.IsPaneOpen = false;
            }
            else
            {
                this.splitView.IsPaneOpen = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please add some  code here

Comment: Edited! ButtonMenuClick is called when I click button to open pane of Hamburger menu, but ever content dialog is open and I need this still open.

Comment: Have you looked into using the Z-index?

Comment: I don't have any Z-index in both elements, it is by default.

Comment: Please add your *`Xaml` code* ...these c# codes aren't useful

Comment: + U can use : `splitView.IsPaneOpen=!(splitView.IsPaneOpen);`  instead of if-else

Comment: I don't think it can be done, because content dialog always appear on top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and not sure without code as Shahriar mentioned if this is going to help but I needed the hamburger menu to be seperate to the split view so here is my solution if it helps.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33623056/495420